# Where are my icons in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, icons

In previous versions of Windows when I right click on a shortcut and dived in to change the icon the initial list populated with a whole catalog of default icons.

On Windows 7 (RTM) here is what I see:

[image: Icons in Windows 7]

I found those icons useful when making shortcuts to web applications.

Any idea where I can find them?! I had a little "Browse..." but couldn't find much.

**Edit:**

You've all so far provided excellent answers, thanks - unfortunately I can't pick you all as the right one! :( Three of the files you mentioned have had equally useful sets of DLLs:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\imageres.dll
%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll
%SystemRoot%\system32\DDORes.dll
%SystemRoot%\System32\moricons.dll (MS DOS Icons)
```

Comment: note that it's illegal to share these icons

Comment: to easily find, preview and save such icons (from dll, exe etc) see [this aplication](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/iconsext.html)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

In the box that says “Look for icons in this file:”, type or browse to:
    `%SystemRoot%\system32\SHELL32.dll`

Answer (score 40):

The can be all over the place.  For example, browse to this location ...

```
C:\Windows\system32\imageres.dll
```

But, they can be in any DLL, EXE or ICO file. You can also [download cool ones](http://www.windows7icons.com/).

Comment: ImageRex.dll started with Vista, and provides the new, high-resolution, 256x256 icons. Shell32.dll maintains icons that have been around for over a decade (including the MS-DOS icon :)  )

Answer (score 35):

There are more than 1,000 icons in total in these files:

- `C:\Windows\System32\Shell32.Dll`
- `C:\Windows\Explorer.Exe`
- `C:\Windows\System32\AccessibilityCpl.Dll`
- `C:\Windows\System32\Ddores.Dll`
- `C:\Windows\System32\GameUx.Dll`
- `C:\Windows\System32\imageres.dll`
- `C:\Windows\System32\MorIcons.Dll`
- `C:\Windows\System32\mmcndmgr.dll`
- `C:\Windows\System32\mmRes.Dll`
- `C:\Windows\System32\NetCenter.Dll`
- `C:\Windows\System32\netshell.dll`
- `C:\Windows\System32\networkexplorer.dll`
- `C:\Windows\System32\PifMgr.dll`
- `C:\Windows\System32\PniDui.Dll`
- `C:\Windows\System32\SensorsCpl.Dll`
- `C:\Windows\System32\SetupApi.Dll`
- `C:\Windows\System32\wmploc.DLL`
- `C:\Windows\System32\wpdshext.dll`
- `C:\Windows\System32\DDORes.dll`
- `C:\Windows\System32\compstui.dll`

Answer (score 15):

Additionally, lots of device icons are stored here:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\DDORes.dll
```

and high res stuff from devices and printers (potentially) here:

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Device Metadata\dmrccache\
```

Answer (score 11):

There are 113 additional icons in:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\moricons.dll
```

Answer (score 2):

The real decade-long legendary MS-DOS icons secretly reside in `pifmgr.dll` dynamic library file with the description of `Windows NT PIF Manager Icon Resources Library` in `System32` folder of root of Windows contained in `%windir%` environment variable, that's `C:\Windows\System32` by default.

[image: Good old MS-DOS icons]

Answer (score 1):

Looking for a new ICON for an application on your Windows 7 screen? Goto the bottom of your screen and click on "Start".

In the Search Programs and Files box, enter *.ico. Above it, you will see - "see more results" -select it and then select "Computer". Your Windows 7 search engine will then find and show you EVERY ICON that's in your computer - sit back, this might take a minute or two (you've got Icons scattered all over your computer). To put them ALL in one place, after your search engine stops, copy them ALL into a single folder and they'll always be available for you. Have fun everyone...

Comment: This is a true power user answer

Comment: I don't think that this won't show icons hidden away in DLL files though

Answer (score 0):

Several good answers but no one seems to have the capitalization quite right (to make copy-paste actually work).

This was my path:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\shell32.dll
```

Answer (score -2):

the procedures are the same in Windows 7 and Windows 8.

1. Create a folder named Taskbar Shortcuts.
2. Move it to c:\Windows
3. Create a shortcut for the desired item within this folder.
4. Decide on the icon to be used for your Taskbar Shortcut
   (you may have to go to step 5)
   (do not try to apply the icon yet)
5. Right-click and drag the shortcut without releasing.
   (This may give you an idea of the true icon)
   (do not do any more here)
6. Icon Selection

   A. To apply a specific icon to your shortcut right-click\
      properties\change icon

   B. By default windows will offer you icons in the shell32.dll
      look through them to see if the desired icon is there.
      If it is then select it and click OK.

   C. If you can't locate your specific icon then follow these steps:

   ```
   1c. Open Windows Explorer
   2c. Select Computer in the left pane.
   3c. Type the following in the Search Bar: *.ico
   4c. Once the progress bar stops scroll down the list to see
      if you can locate the desired icon.
   5c. If unable to locate the icon then look at the following
      list of possible locations. Select one of the strings and press ctrl-c

             C:\Windows\Explorer.Exe
             C:\Windows\System32\AccessibilityCpl.Dll
             C:\Windows\System32\Ddores.Dll
             C:\Windows\System32\GameUx.Dll
             C:\Windows\System32\imageres.dll
             C:\Windows\System32\MorIcons.Dll
             C:\Windows\System32\mmcndmgr.dll
             C:\Windows\System32\mmRes.Dll
             C:\Windows\System32\NetCenter.Dll
             C:\Windows\System32\netshell.dll
             C:\Windows\System32\networkexplorer.dll  (Local Area Connection)
             C:\Windows\System32\PifMgr.dll
             C:\Windows\System32\PniDui.Dll
             C:\Windows\System32\SensorsCpl.Dll
             C:\Windows\System32\SetupApi.Dll
             C:\Windows\System32\wmploc.DLL
             C:\Windows\System32\wpdshext.dll
             C:\Windows\System32\DDORes.dll
             C:\Windows\System32\compstui.dll

   6c. Select the shortcut & right-click\properties\change icon.
      Highlight the text in the location box and press ctrl-v and click OK.
   7c. Repeat the process as necessary to locate your icon.
   ```
7. Once the shorcut has the proper icon Select your shortcut and press ctrl-c
8. Right-click in the Taskbar Shortcuts folder and select
   NEW\SHORTCUT
9. When the New Shortcut Wizard opens key in the following:

   explorer

   space

   ### ctrl-v

   (example: explorer "C:\windows\Taskbar Shortcuts\Local Connection)
   click OK
10. Give the new shorcut a similar but slightly different name from the original and click OK
11. Drag and drop your new shorcut to the windows taskbar.
12. If the new taskbar item needs right click functionality like Local Area Connection-Disable\Enable
    then do this:

    ```
    A. Taskbar right-click\toolbars\new toolbar...

    B. Navigate to c:\Windows\Taskbar Shortcuts and click Select Folder

    C. Go to the new Toolbar folder on the Taskbar right-click & uncheck Show Text & Show Title.
    ```