# How do I change my icons in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, icons

For my last 2–3 computers I've always changed a lot of the Windows stock icons with ones that I ether downloaded, or got from a CD that a friend of mine gave me back in 2000. In Windows 98 and Windows XP I'd just go to a folder and install them there.

With Windows 7, how can I use my custom one of a kind icons?

There's no folder to put them in, and when I try to right click and just use the old... Properties, change icon, it keeps looking for folders also. So when I get to the icon itself, it wants to "open it" instead of "installing it".

And in the registry – `%SystemRoot%\system32\SHELL32.dll` – how can I add other icons to it? It won't let me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any editor (eg [*Resource Hacker*](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/)) to add more icons to windows by editing the file resources images ([*imageres.dll*](https://superuser.com/questions/25086/where-are-my-icons-in-windows-7/25095#25095)). I suggest you to use icons from *256x256* and above.

**[`This`](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3qIAa0YyRoI)** video explains what I am saying.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a folder and put your icons files (with .ico extension) in it.Once you need to change an icon for any shortcut or program , just browse for it and select the icon that you want.