# Change default location of icons

Tags: windows-10, icons

When clicking the properties of any given folder in Windows File Explorer we have the option to change the folder icon. When we click on this a default path is chosen showing us the contents of:

`%SystemRoot%\System32\SHELL32.dll`

[image]

Is there a way to change what this default directory is? I have my own icon folder that I would like it to default to.

Running Windows 10 Pro

Comment: This gives you some ideas for making your own icon file.   I have not yet found a way to change the default.   https://www.windowschimp.com/windows-10-icon-location/

Comment: There is no "default directory".  These are individual registry entries even though they use a system wide variable for the %SystemRoot% folder.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas So every time that properties window is opened it just randomly picks a  %SystemRoot% folder and it just happens it's the same one every single time?

Comment: @John thanks for the info but I have already bookmarked [this awesome answer ](https://superuser.com/a/559357/598567) for that purpose. There must be a reg value somewhere that governs this.

Comment: No, it doesn't "randomly" pick a path.  Open regedit.  Navigate to the root of HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.  Search for `%SystemRoot%\System32\SHELL32.dll`.  Over and over, you will find this DLL holds the keys to most of the icons used in Windows.  These icons are assigned and not "random".  The path is going to be pointed at the one in the registry by default if you go to change it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this behavior is built-into Windows and cannot be changed.
In any case, the prompt is to a *file* containing the icon or icons,
and not to a folder.

The fastest route I can see to get to your folder is to click the
"Browse..." button, and have your folder pinned into the Quick Access,
so that you can position to it with one click.

Reference :
[How to Use Windows 10 Quick Access](https://www.lifewire.com/windows-10-quick-access-4587235).

Comment: Yes the prompt looks for file, but it does so in a directory. The question asks how to change which directory it defaults to.

Comment: It defaults to the directory where resides the actual icon. If the executable pointed-to by the shortcut doesn't have an icon of its own in its resource-block, a default icon from `SHELL32.dll` will be used.

Comment: Thanks @harrymc .. I essentially said the same thing above before I saw your comment.  And most of the things being referenced are shell objects.  If not assigned, it will either try to use the ICON resource at index 0 from the COM DLL or go with the generic windows default document icon.  This is hardcoded in explorer.exe.